# What threads are used in a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, threadpool

I'm looking to **understand the thread usage** in various types of applications and I'm a bit surprised that **WPF apps have 2 more threads** (besides the UI thread) that I didn't expect.

I followed these steps:

1. create new WPF app
2. press `F5` to start it in debug mode
3. go to `Debug -> Windows -> Parallel Stacks`
4. press `Break All` button
5. investigate the `Parallel Stacks` window

I expected to get a single thread - the UI thread, but got 3 threads instead:

[image: WPF default threads]

The leftmost thread is the UI thread - which I expected all along, but **what are the other 2 threads used for**? I didn't create them - I just made a barebones WPF app - no modifications to the initial code generated by the new project wizard.

Also **how do I use the functions** indicated with red arrows in the screenshot above:

1. `ProtocolHandler.SendThread`
2. `ProtocolHandler.ReadThread`

I looked for the documentation, but didn't find much info on these. I also tried to use them in the code behind, but there are no using statements to add - they are just unrecognized.

Comment: I get different looking threads (probably depends on .NET version). If you kick the program off from outside VS, and then attach, do you still see the threads?

Comment: I just tried: yes, I get exactly the same threads as before. I started a release version of the app from outside VS, attached to process and used break all. Same threads in Parallel Stacks.

Comment: What is your WPF version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The full namespace of the `ProtocolHandler` class is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WpfTap.Networking`. As the name indicates, it's used by the design debugging tools from Visual Studio (likely the one that allows to inspect/modify the UI at runtime).

If you disable those tools in Visual Studio (Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Uncheck "Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML"), you'll see that the two extra threads won't be started anymore.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot for explaining it so clearly!